# What is an elegant way to shut down a chain of goroutines linked by channels?

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I'm a Go learner. In order better to understand the care and feeding of channels and goroutines, I'm trying to build a Sieve of Eratosthenes as a set of goroutines connected into a pipeline by channels.

Here's what I have so far:

```
// esieve implements a Sieve of Eratosthenes
// as a series of channels connected together
// by goroutines
package main

import "fmt"

func sieve(mine int, inch chan int) {
    start := true                        // First-number switch
    ouch := make(chan int)               // Output channel for this instance
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", mine)             // Print this instance's prime
    for next := <-inch; next > 0; next = <-inch {  // Read input channel
        fmt.Printf("%v <- %v\n",mine,next)         // (Trace)
        if (next % mine) > 0 {                     // Divisible by my prime?
            if start {                   // No; is it the first number through? 
                go sieve(next, ouch)     // First number - create instance for it
                start = false            // First time done
            } else {                     // Not first time
                ouch <- next             // Pass it to the next instance
            }
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    lim := 30                     // Let's do up to 30
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", 2)         // Treat 2 as a special case
    ouch := make(chan int)        // Create the first segment of the pipe
    go sieve(3, ouch)             // Create the instance for '3'
    for prime := 3; prime < lim; prime += 2 { // Generate 3, 5, ...
        fmt.Printf("Send %v\n", prime)        // Trace
        ouch <- prime                         // Send it down the pipe
    }
}
```

And as far as it goes, it works nicely.

However, when I finish the main loop, `main` exits before all the numbers still in the pipeline of `sieve` instances have propagated down to the end.

What is the simplest, most elegant, or generally accepted way to make a main routine wait for a set of goroutines (about which it only 'knows' of the first one) to complete?

Comment: Simplest and recommended solution is to use another channel that `main` will block on and receive a result of the operation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shutdown “worker” go routine after buffer is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32383063/shutdown-worker-go-routine-after-buffer-is-empty)

Comment: @icza : I agree partly; that question involves a simpler (sort-of star) topology. In my case, only the last goroutine in the pipe must signal shutdown, *once it knows it's last* . I think I'm close to the final answer, which I'll end up posting here. BTW delightful constructs to use!

Comment: @creker : Thank you. That's helped me to see how I have to solve the problem, so if you care to post as an answer, I'll accept. I also plan to post the result as my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

**As for your title question, killing worker goroutines when you don't need them anymore:**
You could use the Done idiom. Reads from a closed channel yield the zero value.

Make a new channel `done`. When reads from this channel succeed, the goroutines know they should quit. Close the channel in main when you have all the values you need.

Check if you can read from a channel `done`, and exit by returning, or read from next when that's available. This partially replaces the assignment to `next` in you for loop:

```
select {
case <-done:
return
case next = <- inch:
}
```

Ranging over a channel also works, since closing that channel exits the loop.

**As for the reverse, your body question, waiting for a set of goroutines to finish:**

Use `sync.WaitGroup`.

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(goroutineCount)
```

And when each goroutine finishes:

```
wg.Done()
```

Or use defer:

```
defer wg.Done()
```

To wait for all of them to report as Done:

```
wg.Wait()
```

In your example, simply call `wg.Add(1)` when you start a new goroutine, before you call `wg.Done()` and return. As long as you only reach zero once, `wg.Wait()` works as expected, so `wg.Add(1)` before `wg.Done`.

Answer (score 0):

After [@izca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1705598/icza) unblocked my logjam, and after a few false starts involving deadlocks when everything finished, here's my solution working correctly:

```
// esieve implements a Sieve of Eratosthenes
// as a series of channels connected together
// by goroutines
package main

import "fmt"

func sieve(mine int,                  // This instance's own prime
           inch chan int,             // Input channel from lower primes
           done chan int,             // Channel for signalling shutdown
           count int) {               // Number of primes - counter
    start := true                     // First-number switch
    ouch := make(chan int)            // Output channel, this instance
    fmt.Printf("%v ", mine)           // Print this instance's prime
    for next := <-inch; next > 0; next = <-inch { // Read input channel
        if (next % mine) > 0 {        // Divisible by my prime?
            if start {                // No; first time through?
                go sieve(next, ouch, done, count+1) // First number,
                                                    // create instance for it
                start = false         // First time done
            } else {                  // Not first time
                ouch <- next          // Pass to next instance
            }
        }
    }
    if start {                        // Just starting?
        close(done)                   // Yes - we're last in pipe - signal done
        print("\n",count," primes\n") // Number of primes/goroutines
    } else {
        close(ouch)                   // No - send the signal down the pipe
    }
}

func main() {
    lim := 100                        // Let's do up to 100
    done := make(chan int)            // Create the done return channel
    ouch := make(chan int)            // Create the first segment of the pipe
    go sieve(2, ouch, done, 1)        // Create the first instance for '2'
    for prime := 3; prime < lim; prime += 1 { // Generate odd numbers
        ouch <- prime                         // Send numbers down the pipe
    }
    close(ouch)                       // Send the done signal down the pipe
    <- done                           // and wait for it to come back
}
```

I'm tremendously impressed with the elegance and simplicity of Go for this kind of programming, when compared with many other languages. Of course, the warts I claim for myself.

If appropriate here, I'd welcome critical comments.

Comment: In sieve(), you define a local 'start' variable by using the ':=' syntax. That means each sieve goproc you invoke will think it is the starting proc.

Comment: @maurice Sorry, the name may have been badly chosen. The intent of the start variable is that it is local to each goroutine, and tells it whether or not it has completed startup by reading the first prime that makes it all the way down the pipe so far to this goroutine. Have I got that wrong? (I've always been bad at choosing variable names.)

Comment: ah, I see now that you allow each goproc sieve to close the child input only if it spawned a child. Got it. Thx.

Comment: @maurice : Yes, that's it. All the «goproc sieve»s that have spawned a downstream instance close the channel to it; the last instance, which hasn't spawned, just closes the «done» channel to signal the main task to end.